# GitHub API: Get Pinned Repositories

Tags: github, github-api

I was looking in the documentation but I couldn’t find how to do this. As the title says: How to get a user’s pinned repositories using the GitHub API ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The pinned repositories data is not available on GitHub v3 API. But you can use GitHub's v4 GraphQL API to get the same with the GraphQL query below:

```
{
  user(login: "GabrielBB") {
    pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
      nodes {
        ... on Repository {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The curl request for the above query:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.github.com/graphql' \
-H 'Authorization: bearer <token>' \
--data-raw '{"query":"{\n  user(login: \"GabrielBB\") {\n pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {\n nodes {\n ... on Repository {\n name\n }\n }\n }\n }\n}"
'
```

The response for the above request:

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "pinnedItems": {
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "name": "xtate"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "vscode-lombok"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "react-use-session"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Android-CutOut"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "xvfb-action"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Vehicles-API"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: You need to generate a **token** to access the GraphQL API, which you can generate by following the steps given [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)